# How to fix my delayed loop which stuck after the 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, google-chrome, asynchronous

I would like to create a Jscript which I would paste to the Google Chrome Consol, and it should copy the innerHTML part of an element to the clipboard.
This should be done in every for a long period of time.

So far I managed to write a code which loops from 0 to 9, calling the function which copies the content to the clipboard, then sleeps for 1 seconds. It also writes to the console the the number of loops and the data itself.

```
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    function mycopy() {
        var copy = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var text = document.getElementsByClassName("md-tile")[0].innerHTML
            text = text.substring(0,10)
            console.log(text);
            if (e.clipboardData) {
                e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
            } else if (window.clipboardData) {
                window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener('copy', copy);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        window.removeEventListener('copy', copy);
    }

    var text = "a"
    for (let XYZ = 0; XYZ < 10; XYZ++) {
        console.log('copy' + XYZ + ' Sec');
        text = ""
        mycopy();
        await sleep(1000);
    }
    console.log('Done');
```

As far I understand with my limited knowledge, the above script should 
copy the the inner HTML of the first element where the class is "md-title".

However it will stop copying exactly after 5 seconds. ( it is still 5 seconds if we change the sleep time.)

This is the response in the consol:

copy0 Sec
div class
copy1 Sec
div class
copy2 Sec
div class
copy3 Sec
div class
copy4 Sec
div class
copy5 Sec
copy6 Sec
copy7 Sec
copy8 Sec
copy9 Sec
Done

Is there any idea how to get around this? 
Is there a time limit for reaching the clipboard after 5 seconds?
Is it a chrome limitation, or windows (7)?

Comment: I believe the function to copy to the clipboard is only allowed in a function triggered by a user input event. It can't be used in other code, like `setTimeout()`.

Comment: If this is the case, why does it work in the first 5 seconds? That is what makes me wonder.

Comment: It works because chrome (and probably other browsers too) probably has a grace period from post user input that allows you to set the clipboard.

Comment: Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I managed to solve my issue, however I was not able to use the clipboard as we loose access to it after 5 seconds.

My solution was that I downloaded the HTML part as txt.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function download(filename, text) {
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + text);
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element);
}

for (let XYZ = 0; XYZ < 10; XYZ++) {
    var text0 = document.getElementById('lastUpdate').innerHTML     
    download("DialogLiveLogTime.txt",text0);
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log('Round: ' + XYZ)
}
```

With the above code the Google chrome will download the inner HTML as txt file. Originally this would popup a Save As window, but you can turn that off in the Chrome options menu, plus you can set the destination there.
In the meantime it can be wise to delete the downloaded logs with the same frequency or after read,  with a different script.